# C#: How can I use delegate to find a function on an object and call it

Tags: c#, function, delegates

I would like to have a function like this:

```
Event.Call<Interface>(objectWithThatInterface, (x) => x.MethodOnObject);
```

So the method will be called on this object.
But I have no idea how to do this.
Maybe something with delegates?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just write `objectWithThatInterface.MethodOnObject()` ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use this on an entity component system.

Comment: what about adding an Extention method to Interface ?

Comment: It have to be dynamic and Interface should be any interface ;)

Comment: Could please provide more details on what you try to archieve? Generally like a small example with some classes an code we can make sense of.

Comment: Why is the method `Call` hanging off of a object/class called `Event`? Are you expecting this to have anything to do with events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that this is very simply achieved with this:

```
public static class Event
{
    public static void Call<T>(T instance, Action<T> method) where T : Interface
    {
        method(instance);
    }
}
```

I have purposely avoided putting in any error checking to keep the code simple, but it should probably throw null reference exceptions if either of the parameters are `null`.

Comment: Thanks, helps a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

**Implement event class:**

```
class Event
{
    public static void Call<TInstance>(TInstance instance, Action<TInstance> action)
        where TInstance : IInterface
    {
        // invoke your instance
        action(instance);
    }
}
```

**Implement concrete class:**

```
class ConcreteObject
    : IInterface
{
    public void MethodOnObject()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Called MethodOnObject()");
    }
}
```

**Implement interface:**

```
interface IInterface
{
    void MethodOnObject();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
IInterface objectWithThatInterface = new ConcreteObject();

Event.Call<IInterface>(objectWithThatInterface, x => x.MethodOnObject());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: What's the benefit of introducing `Expression<>` and a `expression.Compile()` step in this code?

Comment: @Crite - Bear in mind that there is a memory hit every time that `expression.Compile()` is called as a new in-memory assembly is loaded and compiled to allow the expression to be executable. Loaded assemblies do not get unloaded so it is effectively a memory leak.